# Does the raspberry pi 3 wifi allows to connect to ad-hoc wifis?

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3, wifi-direct

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to a GoPro Hero 4 camera that supports ad-hoc wifi connections so I can script some photo timelapses.

I'm able to connect from a Windows machine, but unable from the RPi3.

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo -i
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid "goPro4_02"
ifconfig wlan0 10.5.5.20 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Also I scanned first the available WiFi interfaces with the `iwlist` command to identify properly the ESSID and the quality of the signal.

Comment: Hi I know this is strange, but can you try using Cygwin and then connect to your Pi? I use ad-hoc networks everyday and I use Linux on my laptop and I can connect to any Pi easily. The reason I am asking you this is because Windows may not be able to let you access an unsecure Ad-Hoc Network. Use some POSIX libs like Cygwin and it may work.

Comment: I have no problema accessing the RPi3, I'm able to connect perfectly through ssh with the wired network and with the wifi when the RPi3 is connected to my wireless router. The problem is when I try to connect the RPi3 to a GoPro camera using the ad-hoc wireless.

Comment: ah! i see. It should work if all the parameters are similar. no Pings work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am far from being an expert on ad-hoc networks, but it is possible. See [Ad Hoc setup in RPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/ad-hoc-setup-in-rpi-3/49792#49792)

What you have may work, but unless you disable the network management software you will have a conflict

Comment: But this explains how to setup pi 3 as an ad-hoc , not on how to connect to a device configured with ad-hoc. Or is it the same?.

Comment: Ad-hoc networks are non-hierarchical. All need similar settings (obviously different IP).