# Connecting to RPi 3 ad-hoc network from windows PC

Tags: pi-3, networking, wireless, windows

I have recently started working on ad-hoc connection of Raspberry Pi 3.  I am having difficulties creating an ad-hoc connection between windows 8 or 10 pc and the Raspberry Pi 3. I`ve tried to configure my RPi 3 ad-hoc as saying on this link [Ad Hoc setup in RPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/ad-hoc-setup-in-rpi-3) and my configured code is shown below;

/etc/network/interfaces at RPi 3:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.1.1.38
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
    wireless-essid PiAdHocnet
    wireless-channel 1
    # wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf



iface default inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

After this configuration, I reboot RP 3 and also reset wifi as

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

then ad-hoc connection appears on windows 10 computer' s wifi list but when I try to connect, it says "can not connect to this network".  cannot seem to find a solution to this problem, and no other documentation that I have read has contained any helpful information. Can you help me how can I connect my windows 8 or 10 computer to Raspberry Pi 3 ad-hoc?

When I follow instruction in [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/22/raspberry-pi-wireless-communication/) link  and changed
      `address 10.1.1.38`
with
      `address 192.168.1.1`
and 
      `wireless-essid PiAdHocnet`
with
      `wireless-essid RasbiNet`, 
somehow I can connect to RPi 3 ad-hoc network by iPhone 5S

> 

[image]

Comment: I figured out how to connect RPi 3 ad-hoc network from windows 8 and 10. After my last modification (changed address 10.1.1.38 with address 192.168.1.1 and wireless-essid PiAdHocnet with wireless-essid and RasbiNet), I gave 192.168.1.3 IP to my wifi. Wireless network picker in Windows 8 and 10  doesn't show ad-hoc networks, connecting must be done by hand. For connect to an ad-hoc WiFi network in Windows follow this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/56ff83ff-1f15-4fc1-aa37-6651340d46fa/windows-81-connecting-to-ad-hoc-networks?forum=w8itpronetworking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a DHCPv4 server running on your Pi Windows usually will be very sad. So sad. The ISC DHCPv4 server can be easily installed, from package `isc-dhcp-server`. Make sure to adapt its config file to reference the IPv4 subnet you have assigned to `wlan0` where your AP is.