# temporarily change network interface config without saving

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

I am looking for an elegant way to implement fallback behavior for the onboard Wifi. I want the raspberry pi to set up its own ad-hoc AP when it is not able to connect to an existing network.

For now, I intend to have it make this decision on boot (so that if i lose a connection to a network and I want it to start up in ad hoc mode I would reboot), so in my rc.local I determine if `hostname -I` produces anything, if not I want to configure ad hoc mode.

[here is an example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/49792/14164) of instructions for doing just that, but I am hoping to find out if there is a way that I can do it without changing the file and saving it, because if I change the system configuration then it will stay as that upon reboot. I want it to revert back to original wpa_supplicant behavior upon reboot always and only set wlan0 up as ad-hoc when wpa_supplicant cannot connect to a network during boot.

So far the only thing I can think of is to change `/etc/network/interfaces` to ad-hoc config, restart networking, and then change `/etc/network/interfaces` back. This way there is only a small race condition during which a reboot would have the system stuck in ad-hoc mode during boot.

Comment: You may want to use the *NetworkManager* (comes with a CLI, too) instead of *ifup*. It's meant for this purpose.

Comment: this is all about doing it headless and automated, though

Comment: And? As said, the NetworkManager has a command line interface (CLI) which can be used both to automate switching between preconfigured connections and to create/delete configurations. Look up *nmcli*.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I missed that! Will take a look. Thank you!