# Raspberry zero as Hotspot

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, raspbian-stretch, hotspot

I try to let my Zero W act as a hotspot, but my command

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 channel 1 essid HOTSPOT mode ad-hoc
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

deliveres

> Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
>       SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

any ideas ?

I know there is a solution [Ad Hoc setup in RPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/ad-hoc-setup-in-rpi-3) doing it with change of /etc/network/interfaces but I want to **do it with command line** and not change of any files. 
A real ad-hoc  !

Comment: Regarding the duplicate, the Pi 3 and the Zero W use the same wifi chip.

Comment: I want to do it with command line as described. Anyone who knows what preventing this ?

Comment: The problem with that is you are potentially in conflict with the system configuration.  I'm not saying it can't be done that way, but first you have to demonstrate to demonstrate: 1) That you've removed the interface from the system configuration, 2) That you are doing this with appropriate privilleges (i.e., via `sudo` or as root).