# Multiple Raspberry Pi WiFi NetWorking

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless

I have 10 Rasp. I want to communicate them with each other. Making one of them as an hot-spot Wi-Fi access point and connect the other 9 Rasp. to it, is possible. But it is not fault tolerant. If the Wi-Fi Hotspot Rasp. fails, then all the networking will be broken. Rest of the 9 Rasp. cannot communicate each other. Any idea? 
How can I configure, each Raspberry to become an access point whenever needed?

Comment: I think you would want to look at mesh networking

Comment: There are many tutorials online that will teach how to setup a Raspberry Pi as an AP. Select one that fits you OS version.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is called Ad Hoc WiFi. That answer can be found here:
[Ad Hoc setup in RPi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49660/ad-hoc-setup-in-rpi-3)

Comment: Thanks. What is the capacity of on board Wi-Fi? How many of them connect each other in an ad-hoc manner?

Comment: (addressing the "how many" question)...since the same processor serves WiFi and all of the other computational functions, the number of devices that can effectively communicate will depend on all of the other activity on the device. My advice is to try it out and see, or start a new question (or both)