# How many RPi 3 can connect each other in an ad-hoc manner using WiFi adapters?

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, wireless

How many RPi 3 can connect each other in an ad-hoc manner using WiFi adapters? What are the possible problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Raspberry Pi WiFi NetWorking](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93740/multiple-raspberry-pi-wifi-networking)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question two times.